# Calculating Cell label height in sizeForItemAtIndexPath CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I want to resize the height of collectionView cellNib. What's the best way of going about this. I want to resize it because of the sizeToFits I have on a label.

I've been trying to get the height but everytime I attempt to get a cell from inside SizeForItemAtIndexPath an error is thrown. Is there a way I could get the label height or is there an alternative such as tags?

Comment: - use autolayout, set label top and bottom anchors zero by cell and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension for cells height. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) is a sample.

Comment: It's a CollectionView not a table view though

Comment: not matters, you can do the same thing with `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: How can I do the same?